# Как сократить данный код?

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

Программу пишу с помощью Scene Builder c JavaFX. На видео показано как работает программа.

При клике на кнопку(коричневый квадрат слева) из неё выползает блок с настройками, а лейбл с текстом справа отьезжает вправо. Так происходит для каждой кнопки.То есть каждый лейбл привязан к своему коричневому квадрату напротив. При клике на каждый квадрат вызывается метод, который делает анимацию лейблов. и таких методов я сделал 8(на каждый лейбл)

Код работает хорошо. НО! его блин много) я знаю,что эту логику можно как-то сократить,чтобы одну и ту же анимацию заново не создавать для каждой нажатой кнопки.

ВОПРОС №1: как сократить код?

ВОПРОС №2: Можно ли это сделать с помощью оператора Switch?

ВОПРОС №2-1: Как это сделать?

ВОПРОС №3: Можно ли перенести всю логику обработки анимаций в отдельный класс, чтобы этот класс Controller освободить для других операций?

Хотелось бы в идеале иметь отдельный класс Animation.java который бы отвечал чисто за анимацию всех элементов, но который был виден в то же время главному классу Main и классу Controller

Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

[ВИДЕО](https://hdd.tomsk.ru/desk/wshyeozz#)

Класс Main:

```
package card;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.input.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.StageStyle;

public class Main extends Application {

  //create variables for draggable window


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    try {

      Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/card/card.fxml"));
      Scene scene = new Scene(root, 1600, 600);
      primaryStage.setScene(scene);
      scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
      primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
      primaryStage.setMaximized(true);
      primaryStage.setResizable(true);
      ResizeHelper.addResizeListener(primaryStage);
      primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("card/resources/logo-icon.png"));
      primaryStage.show();

      //assign ALT+ENTER to maximize window
      final KeyCombination kb = new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.ENTER, KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN);
      scene.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
          if (kb.match(event)) {
            primaryStage.setMaximized(!primaryStage.isMaximized());
            primaryStage.setResizable(true);

          }
        }
      });

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

Класс Controller:

```
package card;

import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class Controller implements Initializable {


  @FXML  private AnchorPane anchorRow;
  @FXML  private StackPane hBoxCat0;
  @FXML  private Button btnPalette;
  @FXML  private Button btnFont;
  @FXML  private Button btnQuestCards;
  @FXML  private Button btnNonQuestCards;
  @FXML  private ToggleButton btnPref1;
  @FXML  private ToggleButton btnPref2;
  @FXML  private ToggleButton btnPref3;
  @FXML  private ToggleButton btnPref4;
  @FXML  private ToggleButton btnPref5;
  @FXML  private ToggleButton btnPref6;
  @FXML  private ToggleButton btnPref7;
  @FXML  private ToggleButton btnPref8;
  @FXML  private Label category1;
  @FXML  private Label category2;
  @FXML  private Label category3;
  @FXML  private Label category4;
  @FXML  private Label category5;
  @FXML  private Label category6;
  @FXML  private Label category7;
  @FXML  private Label category8;
  @FXML  private ToggleGroup group;

  @FXML
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {


  }


  //show Preference block with icons
  public void showPrefAnimation() {
    Timeline tmHbox = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300), new KeyValue(hBoxCat0.prefWidthProperty(), 250, Interpolator.EASE_BOTH)));

    Timeline ttPalette = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300), new KeyValue(btnPalette.translateXProperty(), btnPalette.getTranslateX() + 40)));
    Timeline ttFont = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300), new KeyValue(btnFont.translateXProperty(), btnFont.getTranslateX() + 93)));
    Timeline ttQuest = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300), new KeyValue(btnQuestCards.translateXProperty(), btnQuestCards.getTranslateX() + 143)));
    Timeline ttNonQuest = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300), new KeyValue(btnNonQuestCards.translateXProperty(), btnNonQuestCards.getTranslateX() + 195)));


    ttPalette.play();
    ttFont.play();
    ttQuest.play();
    ttNonQuest.play();
    tmHbox.play();
  }

  //hide Preference block with icons
  public void hidePrefAnimation() {
    Timeline tmHbox = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300), new KeyValue(hBoxCat0.prefWidthProperty(), 10, Interpolator.EASE_BOTH)));

    Timeline ttPalette = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300), new KeyValue(btnPalette.translateXProperty(), btnPalette.getTranslateX() - 40)));
    Timeline ttFont = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300), new KeyValue(btnFont.translateXProperty(), btnFont.getTranslateX() - 93)));
    Timeline ttQuest = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300), new KeyValue(btnQuestCards.translateXProperty(), btnQuestCards.getTranslateX() - 143)));
    Timeline ttNonQuest = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300), new KeyValue(btnNonQuestCards.translateXProperty(), btnNonQuestCards.getTranslateX() - 195)));

    ttPalette.play();
    ttFont.play();
    ttQuest.play();
    ttNonQuest.play();
    tmHbox.play();

  }


  //switch Row of preference block and make animation for category 1
  @FXML
  void openPreference1(ActionEvent event) {

    if (btnPref1.isSelected()) {
      GridPane.setRowIndex(anchorRow, 0);
      TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), category1);
      tt.setByX(210);
      tt.play();
      showPrefAnimation();
      group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((button) -> button.setDisable(true));
      btnPref1.setDisable(false);
    } else {
      TranslateTransition tt1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), category1);
      tt1.setByX(-210);
      tt1.play();
      hidePrefAnimation();
      group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((button) -> {
        button.setDisable(false);
      });
    }
  }

  //switch Row of preference block and make animation for category 2
  @FXML
  void openPreference2(ActionEvent event) {

    if (btnPref2.isSelected()) {
      GridPane.setRowIndex(anchorRow, 1);
      TranslateTransition tt2 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), category2);
      tt2.setByX(210);
      tt2.play();
      showPrefAnimation();
      group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((button) -> button.setDisable(true));
      btnPref2.setDisable(false);
    } else {
      TranslateTransition tt3 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), category2);
      tt3.setByX(-210);
      tt3.play();
      hidePrefAnimation();
      group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((button) -> {
        button.setDisable(false);
      });
    }

  }

  //switch Row of preference block and make animation for category 3
  @FXML
  void openPreference3(ActionEvent event) {

    if (btnPref3.isSelected()) {
      GridPane.setRowIndex(anchorRow, 2);
      TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), category3);
      tt.setByX(210);
      tt.play();
      showPrefAnimation();
      group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((button) -> button.setDisable(true));
      btnPref3.setDisable(false);
    } else {
      TranslateTransition tt1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), category3);
      tt1.setByX(-210);
      tt1.play();
      hidePrefAnimation();
      group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((button) -> {
        button.setDisable(false);
      });
    }

  }

  //switch Row of preference block and make animation for category 4
  @FXML
  void openPreference4(ActionEvent event) {

    if (btnPref4.isSelected()) {
      GridPane.setRowIndex(anchorRow, 3);
      TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), category4);
      tt.setByX(210);
      tt.play();
      showPrefAnimation();
      group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((button) -> button.setDisable(true));
      btnPref4.setDisable(false);
    } else {
      TranslateTransition tt1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), category4);
      tt1.setByX(-210);
      tt1.play();
      hidePrefAnimation();
      group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((button) -> {
        button.setDisable(false);
      });
    }
  }

  //switch Row of preference block and make animation for category 5
  @FXML
  void openPreference5(ActionEvent event) {

    if (btnPref5.isSelected()) {
      GridPane.setRowIndex(anchorRow, 4);
      TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), category5);
      tt.setByX(210);
      tt.play();
      showPrefAnimation();
      group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((button) -> button.setDisable(true));
      btnPref5.setDisable(false);
    } else {
      TranslateTransition tt1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), category5);
      tt1.setByX(-210);
      tt1.play();
      hidePrefAnimation();
      group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((button) -> {
        button.setDisable(false);
      });
    }
  }

  //switch Row of preference block and make animation for category 6
  @FXML
  void openPreference6(ActionEvent event) {

    if (btnPref6.isSelected()) {
      GridPane.setRowIndex(anchorRow, 5);
      TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), category6);
      tt.setByX(210);
      tt.play();
      showPrefAnimation();
      group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((button) -> button.setDisable(true));
      btnPref6.setDisable(false);
    } else {
      TranslateTransition tt1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), category6);
      tt1.setByX(-210);
      tt1.play();
      hidePrefAnimation();
      group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((button) -> {
        button.setDisable(false);
      });
    }
  }

  //switch Row of preference block and make animation for category 7
  @FXML
  void openPreference7(ActionEvent event) {

    if (btnPref7.isSelected()) {
      GridPane.setRowIndex(anchorRow, 6);
      TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), category7);
      tt.setByX(210);
      tt.play();
      showPrefAnimation();
      group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((button) -> button.setDisable(true));
      btnPref7.setDisable(false);
    } else {
      TranslateTransition tt1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), category7);
      tt1.setByX(-210);
      tt1.play();
      hidePrefAnimation();
      group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((button) -> {
        button.setDisable(false);
      });
    }
  }

  //switch Row of preference block and make animation for category 8
  @FXML
  void openPreference8(ActionEvent event) {

    if (btnPref8.isSelected()) {
      GridPane.setRowIndex(anchorRow, 7);
      TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), category8);
      tt.setByX(210);
      tt.play();
      showPrefAnimation();
      group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((button) -> button.setDisable(true));
      btnPref8.setDisable(false);
    } else {
      TranslateTransition tt1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), category8);
      tt1.setByX(-210);
      tt1.play();
      hidePrefAnimation();
      group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((button) -> {
        button.setDisable(false);
      });
    }

  }


}
```

Comment: т.е. вы воспользовались "автоматическим" генератором кода, и теперь вас не устраивает что код из него "не по феншую" ? Я правильно понимаю суть вопроса и горю желанием посоветовать вам пересеть на ассемблер, и отказаться от всех абстракций, т.к. за ними часто скрывается очень много кода =)

Comment: в смысле автоматическим? я его сам писал) меня не устраивает,то что я не хочу лепить всю логику моей программы в одном классе. А теперь, чтобы реализовать новую функцию программы надо долго скролить код, вообше не айс) Да и к тому же, Intelij Idea мне выделяет участки дублированного кода, она конечно умная среда, но тоже раздражает(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так

```
@FXML
void openPreference1(ActionEvent event) { openPreferenceAction(btnPref1, 0, category1); };
@FXML
void openPreference2(ActionEvent event) { openPreferenceAction(btnPref2, 1, category2); };
....

void openPreferenceAction(ToggleButton button, Integer anchor, Label category) {
    if (button.isSelected()) {
      GridPane.setRowIndex(anchorRow, anchor);
      TranslateTransition tt = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), category);
      tt.setByX(210);
      tt.play();
      showPrefAnimation();
      group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((b) -> b.setDisable(true));
      button.setDisable(false);
    } else {
      TranslateTransition tt1 = new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(300), category);
      tt1.setByX(-210);
      tt1.play();
      hidePrefAnimation();
      group.getToggles().stream().map((toggle) -> (ToggleButton) toggle).forEach((b) -> {
        b.setDisable(false);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Но лучше, например, пройти какие-нибудь курсы по основам программирования, а не полагаться на визуальные конструкторы.

Comment: мне очень удобно делать GUI программы с помощью Scene Builder, я визуально сразу вижу где распологается задуманный мною элемент в окне программы. Программировать учусь на своих же ошибках. Одна из них сейчас в данном коде)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2OTB.jpg

Comment: ошибки вылезли, посмотрите изображение

Comment: точку с запятой то я поставил, но IDEA ругается на button. Вообще, этот раздел с button.Disable я нашел на одном из форумов, но я не знал как по-другому реализовать так,чтобы при нажатии на один из квадратов, все остальные становились Disable. Можно тогда по-другому реализовать метод с Disable toggle buttons ,чтобы избежать ошибки, которая показана на изображении? Вообще эти коричневые квадраты это toggle buttons

Comment: @kentforth поправил, что еще нашел. Но, вообще то, это был пример того, как можно рефакторить код, а не призыв копипастить не глядя. Поменяйте в лямбдах `button` на чтонить другое, например просто `b`

Comment: я прекрасно понимаю,что копипаст это зло, но я бы с удвольствием подкоректировал это решение задачи под себя,если б знал как это сделать)

Comment: благодарю за ответ! вы мне очень помогли, решение работает! А не знаете как можно перенести сей код в отдельный класс, так чтобы все работало?